# Joining a table based on @@servername

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements

How do I use a conditional statement (or any other solution) to determine whether to reference a database that might or might not exist?

I've created a *multi-server* query that correctly returns data from the same database on two different servers. However, Server2 includes a secondary database that doesn't exist on Server1. I need to return a value from that database as well, if it exists.

The following Case statement works as a column for Server1 because the referenced database exists on that server. When run against Server2, I would have expected the 2nd *When* clause to not even be evaluated, but  I receive an "Invalid Object Name" error referencing the non-existent database.

```
CASE 
   WHEN @@SERVERNAME = 'Server2' 
      THEN 'N/A'
   WHEN @@SERVERNAME = 'Server1' 
      THEN (SELECT Column1 FROM databasename.Table1
            WHERE Column1 = a.column1) 
END AS 'AliasName'
```

Note to Self: It seems that a *when* clause is evaluated even though it fails the logical test portion.

[In case it isn't apparent, the **a.column1** reference points to the main (outer) query]

Does anyone have a creative solution to this obstacle?

Comment: SQL is parsed and compile at execution point. If you reference an object that doesn't exist when you try to run that statement it fails. It doesn't even matter if that statement/expression can't ever be executed, the *entire* statement must be valid.

Comment: If you need to run different statements on different environments, you either need to ensure that your applications/instances have different statements for said environments or use dynamic SQL so that a valid statement is created and executed based on the environment.

Comment: T-SQL is actually a compiled language, even though the compilation is on the fly, so including a non-existent object in a query typically doesn't work -- the exception being a stored procedure, where compilation will be deferred, but even there compilation will fail at the moment of execution if the object doesn't exist. Either use dynamic SQL (if this is a one-off) or rewrite this query to use a view or function that will always be present, but will return nothing on `Server2`.

Comment: One option is to create a stored procedure or a view that does the query and thus differs between the two servers but can be called in the same manner from code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my own question, based on the feedback I got:

1. SQL is a compiled language. I knew that, but didn't think of its implications. All objects in a query must actually exist, even though that part of the query might not actually run.
2. Best solution is to create a view or stored procedure on each server specific to that database. They should return the same number of columns. For example: If Server 1 returns data that does not exist on Server 2, the SP from Server 2 should include a blank or null column for the data. Then call each from a multi-server connection to return and join the information from each database.